# Changing values of array in 2nd dimension

Tags: numpy, numpy-ndarray

I have this array:

```
x = numpy.array([[[1, 2, 3]], 
             [[4, 5, 6]],
             [[7,8,9]]])
```

I want to replace the elements 3,6 and 9 with some other numbers.
I tried to split the array to

```
y=x[:,:,:2]
```

and than add the array *new* at the end of array *y* with

```
new = numpy.array([[[10]], 
             [[11]],
             [[12]]])

final_arr= numpy.insert(y,2,new, axis=2)
```

But it adds in each line the new-array.

Comment: Are you asking how to do `x[:, -1] = [10, 11, 12]`?

Comment: Thanks, I found the answer :) I set x[:,:,2:3] = new

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add it to the third dimension, so just create an array with the corresponding shape. You can do easily with the use of `numpy.newaxis`, as shown below:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array(
    [
        [[1, 2, 3]], 
        [[4, 5, 6]],
        [[7,8,9]]
    ])
x[:, :, -1] = np.array([10, 11, 12])[:, np.newaxis]
x
```

**Output**

```
array([[[ 1,  2, 10]],

       [[ 4,  5, 11]],

       [[ 7,  8, 12]]])
```

Cheers!